# Why is differentiation as a linear operator commutative?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In my linear algebra course, on the topic of solving a system of ODEs by diagonalising the matrix, it is taken as granted that if:
$$\mathbf{\dot x} = A\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}=P\mathbf{y}, P^{-1}AP=D$$

Then the equations reduce down to:
$$ \mathbf{\dot y} = D\mathbf{y}$$
But if that is true then 
$$A\mathbf{y} = P^{-1}AP\mathbf{y}$$
$$PA\mathbf{y} = AP\mathbf{y}$$
Then
$$PA = AP$$

Edit: Just read [somewhere](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/312S14/Notes/ODE-system.pdf) that if we denote $\mathbf{x}$ as a function of $t$ then because $P$ does depend on $t$ $P^{-1}\underline{x}'(t) = (P^{-1}\underline{x})'(t) =\underline{y'}(t)$ but I still don't follow, if someone could describe it more fully it would be much appreciated

Comment: HOw did you get that string of equalities(particularly $APy = PAy$ which is clearly false in general)?

Comment: Presumably here $P$ is a "constant" linear operation, with respect to $x$.  So $x = Py$ means something quite different from $\dot x = A x$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $AP \mathbf y = PA \mathbf y$? It looks like you are assuming that $\dot{ \mathbf y} = A \dot{ \mathbf y}$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited my question to make it more coherent

Comment: again, how do you get $Ay = P^{-1}APy$ from $\dot{y} = Dy$? YOu should get $\dot{y} = P^{-1}APy$

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that $\dot y = Ay$? Because $\dot x = Ax$ so surely $Ay = P^{-1}APy$

Comment: Yes, definitely that's wrong; I'm not sure how you arrived at that conclusion. If $\dot{x} = Ax$ and $A = PDP^{-1}$ then $\dot{y} = Dy$. That's it. Why? let's do it step by step. $\dot{x} = Ax$ implies $\dfrac{d}{dt}(Py) = (PDP^{-1})(Py)$. Hence, $P \dot{y} = (PDP^{-1}P)y$. "Cancelling" stuff shows that $\dot{y} = Dy$.

Comment: Remember that these equations are only satisfied by _some_ $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$, not by _every_ $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$. That’s an important detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a not too complicated example: let
$$x(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \\ x_3(t) \end{pmatrix}
, \, Q = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
\textrm{ and } y(t) = Qx(t).$$
We want to show that $\dot{y}(t) = Q\dot{x}(t)$, right? Well, since
$$y(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t)+x_2(t) \\ x_2(t)-x_3(t) \\ x_1(t)+x_2(t)+x_3(t) \end{pmatrix}$$
it follows that 
\begin{align}
\dot{y}(t) 
&= \begin{pmatrix} x_1'(t)+x_2'(t) \\ x_2'(t)-x_3'(t) \\ x_1'(t)+x_2'(t)+x_3'(t) \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1'(t) \\ x_2'(t) \\ x_3'(t) \end{pmatrix} = Q\dot{x}(t).
\end{align}
In general, this is true, if $Q \in \textsf{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$ is a matrix with constant entries, then the derivative of the vector $Qx(t)$ is $Q\dot{x}(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

By you definition of $y$, we have $y = P^{-1}x$. Since $P$ is time independent
$$
\dot{y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(P^{-1}x) = P^{-1}\dot{x} = P^{-1}A\, x = P^{-1}AP\, y = D\, y
$$

If $PA=AP$, then $D=A$ and $\dot{y} = A\,y$. But in general, $AP≠ PA$, so that $D\neq A$ and $\dot{y}\neq A\,y$.